# Custom Object Picklist to create a record on a different custom object

Tags: apex, custom-object, picklist, record-type

I have a Custom Object called Property (`Property__c`) that has a `Sales Status` picklist and another custom object called Proposal (Proposal__c) (I have more objects but we'll focus on one).  There is a Master-Detail Relationship between the two object.  I also added the Proposal ID so my users can click and go directly to th record.

The main objective is to create a record when a picklist in Property Sales Status is selected or changed.

For example, if I select "Proposal" in the Property picklist.  It will create a *NEW* record in the *Proposal Custom Object* (`Proposal__c`). And after filling in the fields and saving it will also update the fields in the "Property" section. (copying Proposal fields in the Property custom object).

The Property Custom Object is the *main source* of everything.  It has all the fields i need so my users does not search and search for proposal for a particular property.  Avoiding all clicking and searching they just look at the property record and it has all the information they need.  My purpose of creating records is for tracking and reporting.

How can I start to code this.  Any guidance will be appreciated.

*UPDATE:* I think after the record is created, I can do a workflow of copy records from a different object.  I just dont know where to start or how to code create a new record in a different custom object when a picklist in the property is selected.

Thanks again

Comment: I think you need to rephrase your question with ellaborated use case description with some specific field info, specifically the part " it will also update the fields in the "Property" section (copying proposal fields in the property custom object)." What is the relationship between the proposal and the property object? (is there a lookup of proposal on the property object?

Comment: It sounds like you want to create a new proposal record. Ok...you want it based off of data in the property. Then once the proposal is created you want to backfill the property with data from the created proposal.

Comment: @RajivBhatt I hope my update is understandable but I think I can create a workflow on the copy proposa part.  Can you help me how to create or start a trigger maybe when a picklist is selected? then it creates a record.

Comment: @Peter  You're about right but when a new record is created in the *proposal object* it will copy those information records and update the empty fields in the property object.   It should also add the relationship ID of the property to the Proposal and vice versa.

Comment: @KingJonathan If I can make a suggestion: Reading between the lines of  your question (and your past questions) it seems there are some holes in your basic understanding of Force.com. I appreciate that behind this there is probably a requirement and a deadline, but you would probably benefit from taking a day (or more) out and just learning some of these things. Maybe work through some of the workbooks on developer.salesforce.com, or working through trailhead developer.salesforce.com/trailhead would help.

Comment: @peter I actually have been working on the developer.salesforce.com.  Thanks on the trailhead and I think that will help